# How to return whole row instead of one column in sequelize literal?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I am using a query and including these attributes but its returning only name of manager i want whole row of data.

```
 attributes: {
      include: [
        [
          Sequelize.literal(
            '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM partnerships WHERE partnerships.business_id = Business.BusinessID AND partnerships.status = "publish")'
          ),
          'campaigns'
        ],
        [
          Sequelize.literal(
            '(SELECT employees.FName FROM client_assignee_logs  LEFT JOIN employees ON employees.LoginID = client_assignee_logs.memberId WHERE client_assignee_logs.businessId = Business.BusinessID AND client_assignee_logs.partnershipId IS NULL AND client_assignee_logs.brandId IS NULL)'
          ),
          'managerName'
        ]
      ]
    },
```

Comment: your SQL doesn't return more than 1 field in any case.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli if i return more fields i get this error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Comment: idk, i think your sql is pretty wrong